# When were the first mosques established in Constantinople?

Tags: religion, islam, byzantine-empire, 13th-century

In his book [*The Man of Numbers*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0802779085) about [Leonardo Pisano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci) (Fibonacci), Keith Devlin quotes a problem from the [*Liber Abbaci*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liber_Abaci) (Devlin's spelling, I know most others spell it Liber Abici) which is titled "A Problem Proposed to Us by a Most Learned Master of a Constantinople Mosque". As *Liber Abbaci* dates to the early thirteenth century (first edition predates the sack of Constantinople by the Fourth Crusade by about 2 years), I want to ask about the date/s of establishment of Mosques in Constantinople?

Comment: AFAIK, the first mosque in Constantinople was built in Chalcedon (Kadıköy)  when the Ottomans conquered the Asian part of the city in 1353. That's over a century after the first publication of Liber Abaci in 1202.

Comment: Is it possible that bit was mistranslated? From the title, I gather that work was in Latin, which ceased to be a living language before Mosques existed.

Comment: @T.E.D. All medieval universities (never mind the churches and monasteries) throughout Europe used Latin for several subsequent centuries so your death of Latin has been exaggerated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](http://constantinople.ehw.gr/Forms/fLemmaBodyExtended.aspx?lemmaID=11800), there are letters to and from a mosque in Constantinople in the 10th century. with speculation it was built for merchants from Muslim countries, as well as for dignitaries, in times of peace between Muslim middle east and christian Byzantine.

Comment: there is also speculation that their was a mosque built outside of the city's walls, during a siege in the 700's that was left up by the byzantine ruler.